# Symfony2 : Using group_by option in an entity field

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I'm trying to display a select box with optgroups in Symfony 2.1.
My entity tree is : client has projects, project has parts (`Part->getProject()->getClient()`)

I want to display my select box this way :

```
<select>
    <optgroup>Client name
        <option>Part name</option>
        <!-- ... -->
    </optgroup>
    <!-- ... -->
</select>
```

The Symfony doc does not help a lot.
My **working** form builder (without group_by option) gives me a simple select :

```
$this->createFormBuilder()
->add('part','entity',array(
    'class'         => 'SGLFLTSPartBundle:Part',
    'property'      => 'name',
    'query_builder' => function (\SGL\FLTS\PartBundle\Entity\PartRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('p');
    }))
->getForm();
```

How do I add the group_by option to display client name? So far I've tried

```
'group_by'      => 'project.client.name'
'group_by'      => 'project.client'
'group_by'      => 'ppc.name' // the DQL table alias
```

All give PHP errors

I've also tried to display the project name only as optgroup, no luck :

```
'group_by'      => 'project'
'group_by'      => 'project.name'
'group_by'      => 'project.id'   // throws no error, giving me <optgroup label="1"> ...
```

and tried adding project/client joins in the createQueryBuilder

```
$er->createQueryBuilder('p')->select('p, pp')->leftJoin('p.project','pp');
$er->createQueryBuilder('p')->select('p, pp.name')->leftJoin('p.project','pp')
// wrong
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar problem today.

I imagine you've been seeing a lot of PHP errors related to the incorrect use of Objects as Array keys? This is caused by Symfony trying to use the whole related object as the array key in the grouped results array.

I'll need to look further into it for a better solution but for the meantime this is what I'm using...

Add a new method to the `Part` entity called `getClientName` that looks like this:

```
public function getClientName()
{
    // safety measure in-case a part hasn't been assigned to a project
    if (null === $this->getProject()) {
        return null;
    }
    // safety measure in-case a project hasn't been assigned to a client
    if (null === $this->getProject()->getClient()) {
        return null;
    }
    return $this->getProject()->getClient()->getName();
}
```

Set the `group_by` option to `clientName` in the form field builder:

```
$this->createFormBuilder()
->add('part','entity',array(
    'class'         => 'SGLFLTSPartBundle:Part',
    // this property will be processed by Symfony as `$part->getClientName()`
    'property'      => 'clientName',
->getForm();
```

The idea behind the use of this extra method is to give Symfony a class method that it can call to get a string value to perform the grouping with.

If anyone else has a more elegant solution I'd be keen to see it.

Comment: Great, thanks. I made an update by adding the 'group_by' option (you wrote 'property'). Also I had an error "Entity was not found." without the inner join inside the query.

Comment: The idea behind the `'group_by' => 'clientName'` option is this: the ObjectChoiceList on line 120 class will use this object property (or class method) to group the objects. As I couldn't get the title of the Client directly from the join in the DQL I needed the `getClientName` method to return this value for me. Joining the related object in DQL should ensure that the related object has already been initialised and won't require a call to the DB for each entity in the collection. The `property` option should still be `group_by`. My examples will need altering to suit your environment.

Comment: Yeah I understand. Still, `createFormBuilder` example array need to be edited as I did before : `'property' => 'name', 'group_by' => 'clientName',`